# Restricting Positive Lookahead when capturing

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I get some text at intervals from stream like,

```
ICY Info: StreamTitle='Elvis Presley - Saved';StreamUrl='';

ICY Info: StreamTitle='Elvis Presley - Saved'

ICY Info: StreamTitle='Ivank'av T'ali - Yorua';StreamUrl='';

ICY Info: StreamTitle='Ivank'av T'ali - Yorua'
```

I wish to obtain

```
Elvis Presley - Saved
Elvis Presley - Saved
Ivank'av T'ali - Yorua
Ivank'av T'ali - Yorua
```

I'm using `(?<=\=\').*(?=';S)` or `(?<=\=\').*(?=')` but they seem not suitable.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mk3bsL/1)

@Edit: I have just come with `(?<=\=\').*?(?=';)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?=';S)`  will not work for the first and the third example when `';S` is not there.

On the other hand `(?=')` Will match too much in the first and the third example.

What you could do is use an alternation in the lookahead to check for either `;:` or `'` followed by the end of the string.

`(?<==').+?(?='(?:;|$))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o8TSD4/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?<==')` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is `='`
- `.+?` Match any character one or more times non greedy
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert that what is on the right is

  - `'(?:;|$)` Match `'` followed by an alternation matching either `;` or assert the end of the string `$`
- `)` close positive lookahead